# netCDF4: Approaches to dealing with multidimensional data with unused grid points

Tags: multidimensional-array, netcdf, netcdf4

I am using netCDF4 to store multidimensional data. The data has, for example, three dimensions, `time = [0, 1, 2]`, `height = [10, 20]`, `direction = [0, 120, 180, 240, 300]`, but not for all combinations (grid points) there is data. In our example, let this be limited to `height`/`direction`-combinations. Namely, suppose that at `height == 10` we have data only for `direction in {0, 120, 240}` and at `height == 20` only for `direction in {120, 180, 300}`.

The approaches for dealing with this I see are:

1. Use a separate unidimensional `Variable` for each `height`/`direction`-combination.
2. Use a single three-dimensional `Variable` over the Cartesian product, i.e., all possible combinations, and live with the fact that for some combinations all values are masked.
3. Use different location dimension definitions for each height and a two-dimensional `Variable` for each height.

Are there other approaches and what are reasons, both principled as well as practical, for preferring one approach over another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your answer number 2 is the correct one.  NETCDF files are gridded files, and so the natural structure for the data describe is to define three dimensions, time, height and direction.  For the array entries for which data does not exist you need to set the data to equal the value defined by the metadata:

```
_FillValue
```

This means that any software such as R, python, ncview etc that is reading the data will assign these points as "missing".

For more details on defining missing values see: 
http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/fill_values.html

Answer (score 0):

When reading up on metadata conventions, I encountered another option: ‘[compression by gathering](http://cfconventions.org/cf-conventions/v1.6.0/cf-conventions.html#compression-by-gathering)’ of the `height` and `direction` variables into a single `location variable`.

How would this work in the toy example? First gather all locations into a one-dimensional list:

```
0: 10,0   *
1: 10,120 *
2: 10,180
3: 10,240 *
4: 10,300
5: 20,0
6: 20,120 *
7: 20,180 *
8: 20,240
9: 20,300 *
```

Then `location = [0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 9]` and data is defined using only two dimensions, `location`, which has a `compress: "height direction"` attribute, and `time`. Probably it is best to add a two-dimensional auxiliary coordinate variable to make the relationship between the location indices and the `height/direction` value explicit: `height_direction = [(10,0), (10,120), (10,240), (20,120), (20,180), (0,300)]`.

Given that there seems to be no library support for this, it is not necessarily the most convenient option in all respects. However, it does seem a legitimate option to consider given that it is encoded in a metadata standard, “[NetCDF Climate and Forecast (CF) Metadata Conventions](http://cfconventions.org/cf-conventions/v1.6.0/cf-conventions.html)”.